# django admin page disable def response_change

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like to replace function of save button in admin page. Default is update, but I would like to insert new value to db.

models.py

```
class user_with_full_info(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=CASCADE)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(branch, on_delete=CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(team, on_delete=CASCADE)
    position = models.ForeignKey(position, on_delete=CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

add_button.html

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
    <!-- hide default save button -->
    <!-- {{ block.super }} -->
    <div class="submit-row">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="_change_position">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

admin.py

```
class UserFullInfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_salary_number', 'user', 'branch', 'team', 'position', 'get_active')

    change_form_template = "information/add_button.html"

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        if "_change_position" in request.POST:
            user_with_full_info.objects.create(
                user = user.objects.get(id = request.POST['user']),
                branch = branch.objects.get(id = request.POST['branch']),
                team = team.objects.get(id = request.POST['team']),
                position = position.objects.get(id = request.POST['position'])
            )              
            return HttpResponseRedirect(".")
        return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

This code is working fine with insert new value, BUT it's always update the selected value too. How can I disable IS_POPUP_VAR in response_change function to not update selected value.

Comment: Django has built-in functionality to "save as new" object when you do editing. It could be configured as an admin class attribute https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_as.

Comment: Thanks you, it's working correctly.